# Back button that pushes to previous view ios

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiview, uitabbar

I've got a "settings" type view that I want to be reachable by every view within my tab navigation. I am able to get to the settings view, but how do I program a button that brings you back to the view that brought you there? For example, if I access the settings view from view 1 I want the back button to bring you back to view 1. Then if I access it from view 2, I want the same back button to bring you back to view 2.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is your view in a navigation controller? If so, use:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

If it's a modal view controller, use:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: Awesome! the ModalView worked since I was using a modal transition i guess. Still learning, but thanks a ton!